# What is this Vine-type plant growing on my Jacaranda tree?

Tags: trees, identification

I have a vine-type plant that is growing on areas of my Jacaranda tree (me + the tree live in Australia). It has little leaves. The roots of the vine grow on the outer-layer of bark on the tree.

Does anyone know what it is and if it will cause any probs over time or hurt the tree in any way?

[image: roots and leaves coming out jacaranda tree]

Answer (score 12):

The plant is a type of orchid. Orchids like to establish themselves on the bark of a tree because they are an epiphytic plant. They like the shade that a tree provides. This plant will in no way harm that huge tree. Most plant lovers would be thrilled to have such a lovely plant given to them for free by nature.

Good luck with plant.

[image]

Comment: That's lovely. Some show gardens try to replicate this, and nature has done it for you. Occasionally you'll see ferns growing in old trees. The orchids are epiphytic and this is the perfect place for it. It will hopefully flower for you.  Have seen this in the wild in Bali.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this to be an epiphytic fern and not an orchid. Most likely Pyrrosia. Please see [What is this epiphytic climbing fern with narrow leathery leaves, found in Thailand?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24191/what-is-this-epiphytic-climbing-fern-with-narrow-leathery-leaves-found-in-thail/24364#24364)