# What is this epiphytic climbing fern with narrow leathery leaves, found in Thailand?

Tags: identification, ferns

Can anybody identify this fern? I found it in the mountains of central Thailand. It is [epiphytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphyte) mostly, but also grows on the ground. 
It has tough leathery leaves and is from an area that has a long dry season.

It was very common in the area that I found it.

[image: fern]

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close - I assumed it was a "test" question in the review queue - This post lacks a question (if there is one, maybe you can reword it so it states a question - its not obvious to me that there is one - are you maybe intending to ask for more specific identification of this fern ?)

Comment: Oh I see, I have edited it now.

Comment: I'd put money on it being a Pyrrosia unless the bet needed to include the species. There are many and they're quite similar and I don't think your picture has enough detail for a specific ID. Start with Pyrrosia lanceolata, Pyrrosia rasamalae, Pyrrosia rupestris or Pyrrosia adnascens.

Comment: @Brenn Thank you, I have seen some Pyrrosia photos now and it is definitely a Pyrrosia. There seems to be many species that look similar, I could have 2 different species in the photo. Good to know someone else appreciates these plants.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad that you agree. I'll add this as an answer and I'll try to include some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the species shown here are both of the genus Pyrrosia. Specific identification might be possible from the given photo but since frond division, a popular method for fern identification, isn't very possible with this genus, you might need to rely on the arrangement of sporangia, (which aren't present in this photo). Since there are about 100 species of Pyrrosia, positive specific identification might require a Pteridologist.

Some species to consider for the longer fronded specimen could include Pyrrosia lanceolata, Pyrrosia rasamalae, Pyrrosia rupestris and Pyrrosia adnascens.

For the ovate fronded specimen, perhaps Pyrrosia nummularifolia or Pyrrosia rupestris.

Pyrrosia Lingua (Shi Wei) is used in traditional Chinese medicine for several ailments: http://www.chineseherbshealing.com/pyrrosia-lingua/

The American Fern Society has published a comprehensive PDF on Pyrrosia which can be found here: http://amerfernsoc.org/ffa/Fiddlehead%20Forum/FF%20Volume%2035-36/Fiddlehead%20Forum%20Vol%2035%20No%202-3.pdf